# CSR Graph Distributed Approach using MPI, having trouble updating result array

Tags: c++, mpi

```
int mpi_vertex_dist(graph_t *graph, int start_vertex, int *result)
{

    int num_vertices = graph->num_vertices; 
    fill_n(result, num_vertices, MAX_DIST);
    
    auto start_time = Time::now();
    
    int depth = 0;
    result[start_vertex] = depth;

    int keep_going = true;    
    int start,stop;
    
    int elements_per_proc = num_vertices / num_proc;
    int remainder = num_vertices % num_proc;
    
    if(my_rank < remainder)
    {
        start = my_rank * (elements_per_proc + 1);
        stop = start + elements_per_proc;
    }
    else
    {
        start = my_rank * elements_per_proc + remainder;
        stop = start + (elements_per_proc-1);
    }
    
    int *resultTmp = new int[num_vertices];

    int count = 0;
    
    while (keep_going)
    {
        keep_going = false;

        for (int vertex = start; vertex <= stop; vertex++)
        {
            if (result[vertex] == depth) {
                for (int n = graph->v_adj_begin[vertex]; 
                    n < graph->v_adj_begin[vertex] + graph->v_adj_length[vertex]; 
                    n++)
                {
                    int neighbor = graph->v_adj_list[n];

                    if (result[neighbor] > depth+1)
                    {
                        result[neighbor] = depth+1;
                        keep_going = true;
                        
                        resultTmp[count] = neighbor;
                    count++;
                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        if(count != 0)
        {
           MPI_Allreduce(resultTmp,result,count, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);      
        }
        
        //  Old Code
        /*
        if(count != 0)
        {
        MPI_Reduce(resultTmp,result,count, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN,my_rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);      
        }
        */
        
        depth++;
    }
    
    
    //print_result(graph, result, depth);
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<us>(Time::now()-start_time).count();
}
```

I managed to split the graph vertices between processors each getting 5 5 4 4 - I have total of 18 in the graph I am using for testing. I keep count of the updates using count. And at the end of the iteration I use that buffer to send to result array using MPI_Allreduce, however when I run the code it doesn't end. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Process zero does a bunch of receives into the `result` array. Each next one overwrites the previous one. You need to add them together or take the max or so.

Comment: Should I do it before receive inside for loop? And which function should I use?

Comment: Since you're doing a bunch of receives and then a broadcast, replace the whole thing by an `MPI_Allreduce`. But that's not actually the biggest problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you approach MPI as if it's shared memory. In your code, each process has a copy of the whole graph, which is wasteful if you ever run this at large scale, but it's not a serious problem for now.

The real problem is the `result` array: each process does reads and writes into it, but each process has a copy of that array, so it does not see the changes that other processes make.

The fix to this problem is that in each iteration of the `while` loop you need to reconcile these copies: do an `Allreduce` with the maximum operator. (I think. I'm not entirely sure what your algorithm is supposed to be.)

Finally, you are using each vertex to update its neigbors. That works fine sequentially, but is not a good design in parallel. Use symmetry, and update each vertex *from* its neigbors. That is a much better design in shared memory and distributed memory both.

Comment: MPI_Allreduce(&result, result, num_vertices, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD ); Is this the code block that I will use, or do I need a temporary array to hold the values and use it as "in" value and the result array as "out" value

Comment: Looks ok. Why don't you work out an example with pen and paper? And then confirm the results. Two processors, 4 node graph with a simple struct, such as a ring.

Comment: But in ring example every process sends to the one after itself and receives from the previous one. In this algorithm I need to every process to update each other.

Comment: Ok, then make a 2 processor, 4 nodes, fully connected graph. Pen and paper, and then see if your program does the same thing. Besides, a ring is simpler, so if your program does not work for a ring, it doesn't work in the general case. There is nothing wrong with starting with a simple example.

Comment: I tried for a very long time, but still couldn't find a solution. I figured out I should use MIN operator and not max operator however I think using "num_vertices" as count is causing the problem        MPI_Allreduce(&result,result,num_vertices, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);     This is the code block that I use right before the return

Comment: `&result,result,` Delete that first ampersand. Both arguments need to be an `int*`, but `&result` is an `int**`. But I would really rewrite the whole code using the strategy from my last paragraph. With MPI an "owner computes" strategy is always better.

Comment: I will try a different and better approach as well but first I want to try this one. Then I will move onto the frontier. But in this case, I get the error "MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer" , I think because of an overhead. I think I just need to do allreduce for the ones where I update the result array. However that's the main part that I can't figure out since I am very new to the MPI

Comment: I also allocated space looking at the example from your book page 36 and used     result = (int*) malloc(num_vertices * sizeof(int));  but this time, in addition to that error I also get the error "PMIX ERROR: UNREACHABLE in file ../../../src/server/pmix_server.c at line 2193"

Comment: You know, if you're just starting with MPI you should not start with such a. complicated example.

Comment: I studied the easier examples first actually and trying to combine them together now. I changed my implementation and edited it in here now

Comment: Okay so I figured out that I am using allreduce even if I don't make an update. I did add a check to see if count is more than zero, else I dont use allreduce

Comment: I don't see that test for he count. Also: your allreduce should be inside the while loop.

Comment: I edited the code now, I moved allreduce inside the while loop, and did the count check as well, however since each process has different counts, allreduce doesn't give me any result and the code keeps running